# Java program to extract coefficents from quadratic equation

Tags: java, regex, string, math

Problem: Java program to split the coefficients from a quadratic equation eg 
if input string is:

```
String str1;
str1 = "4x2-4x-42=0"
```

So I need to split the coefficients from the given input string and to get output as

```
a = 4 b = -4 c = -42
```

I tried this:

```
String equation = "ax2+bx-c=0";
String[] parts = equation.split("\\+|-|=");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length - 2; i++) {
    String part = parts[i].toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(part.substring(0, part.indexOf("x")));
}
System.out.println(parts[2]);
```

But I got the output as 23x2 and 4x and 4.
Actual output needed is `23 ,- 4 , 4`.

Comment: So the input is always of the format `+/-aX2+/-bX+/-c`? Sounds like a job for...regex.

Comment: yes. always in that format

Comment: Do you only need the coefficients? If you intend to get the exponents later on as well, I would recommend building a small Parser for your expressions.

Comment: i need only the coefficients.  if input string is "4x2-4x-42=0"  and "a=4 b=-4 c = -42"  this should be the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regex, the following pattern will work:

```
([+-]?\d+)[Xx]2\s*([+-]?\d+)[Xx]\s*([+-]?\d+)\s*=\s*0
```

This will match the quadratic and extract the parameters, lets work out how it works:

- `(...)` this is capturing group
- `[+-]?\d+` this matches a number of digits, preceded optionally by a `+` or `-`
- `[Xx]` this matches "X" or "x"
- `\s*` this matches zero or more spaces

So

- `([+-]?\d+)` matches the "a" argument
- `[Xx]2` matches "X2" or "x2"
- `\s*` matches optional whitespace
- `([+-]?\d+)` matches the "b" argument
- `[Xx]` matches "X" or "x"
- `\s*` matches optional whitespace
- `([+-]?\d+)` matches the "c" argument
- `\s*=\s*0` matches "=0" with some optional spaces

Lets wrap this in a `class`:

```
private static final class QuadraticEq {
    private static final Pattern EQN = Pattern.compile("([+-]?\\d+)[Xx]2\\s*([+-]?\\d+)[Xx]\\s*([+-]?\\d+)\\s*=\\s*0");
    private final int a;
    private final int b;
    private final int c;

    private QuadraticEq(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public static QuadraticEq parseString(final String eq) {
        final Matcher matcher = EQN.matcher(eq);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid pattern " + eq);
        }
        final int a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        final int b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        final int c = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        return new QuadraticEq(a, b, c);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("QuadraticEq{");
        sb.append("a=").append(a);
        sb.append(", b=").append(b);
        sb.append(", c=").append(c);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Note the `\\`, this is required by Java.

A quick test:

```
System.out.println(QuadraticEq.parseString("4x2-4x-42=0"));
```

Output:

```
QuadraticEq{a=4, b=-4, c=-42}
```

Comment: Error:The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)

Comment: final int a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("a"));
        final int b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("b"));
        final int c = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("c"));

Comment: @JoeMathew are you telling me that you are using Java 6?? It's over ten years old, reaching EOL two years ago. Why??

Comment: Sir i'm using it in my new android app , Is there any way to modify it

Comment: @JoeMathew your question is not tagged [tag:android]. Why? Don't use named groups, and get groups by index.

Comment: @JoeMathew updated the answer to remove those features.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using quadratics:

```
int xsqrd = equation.indexOf("x2");
int x = equation.indexOf("x", xsqrd);
int equ = equation.indexOf("=");
String a = equation.subString(0,xsqrd);
String b = equation.subString(xsqrd+1,x);
String c = equation.subString(x,equ);
```

I may have messed up the substrings but you get the general idea.

Comment: will this code get this output if input string is "4x2-4x-42=0" and "a=4 b=-4 c = -42" this should be the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex as follows:

```
final String regex = "([+-]?\\d+)x2([+-]\\d+)x([+-]\\d+)=0";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

final String equation = "4x2-4x-42=0";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(equation);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int c = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
}
```

Output:

```
a=4 b=-4 c=-42
```

Comment: i'm getting answer as 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

The first note: if you use symbol as delimiter in regexp, you will lose it in slpitted elements. I suggest you use the folllowing regexp:

```
"x2|x|="
```

Then, you can got only numbers. 
The full fragment of code is:

```
public class Main {
    private static final char[] varNames = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String equation = "4x2-4x-42=0";
        String[] parts = equation.split("x2|x|=");
// you will get 4 elements, but the last element is always 0
        for(int i=0; i<parts.length - 1; i++){
            System.out.println(varNames[i] + " = " + Integer.parseInt(parts[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case you will have the '+' symbols in output. To avoid it, you may use `Integer.parseInt(parts[i])` instead of `parts[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < str.length ; ++i ){
  if(asciiOf(str.charAt(i)) == asciiOfIntegerValue ){
    addCharInArrayList(str.charAt(i));
  }else{
      addInFuncList();
      addCharInArrayList("_");
  }


  // join numbers which are not separated by _ and apply BODMAS rule and solve it  
  // fyi : apologies - very inefficient pseudocode, wrote in a haste
```